# How to fix a "invalid operands to binary expression" error?

Tags: c++, variables, pointers, definition

I am inexperienced of using c++ and stuck at the point where compiler generates **invalid operands to binary expression**

```
class Animal{
public:
    int weight;
};

int main(){
    Animal x, y;
    x.weight = 33;
    y.weight = 3;

    if(x != y) {
    // do something
     }
}
```

I want to use x and compare with y, without modifying code i.e. (x.weight != y.weight)in the main code. How should I approach this problem from external class or definition ?

Comment: define `bool operator!=(Animal const& a1, Animal const& a2) { a1.weight != a2.weight; }`

Comment: overload operator `!=` with your own implementation..

Comment: code in main() should be left untouched

Comment: @Martynas Implementing the operator wouldn't need to touch main, it's part of the `class Animal`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alternatively you can add the operator overload as non-member:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Animal{
public:
    int weight;
};

static bool operator!=(const Animal& a1, const Animal& a2) {
    return a1.weight != a2.weight;
}

int main(){
    Animal x, y;
    x.weight = 33;
    y.weight = 3;

    if(x != y) {
        cout << "Not equal weight" << endl;
    } 
    else {
        cout << "Equal weight" << endl;
    }
}
```

- [**Online Demo**](http://ideone.com/pWI2gL)
- [**Member vs nonmember operator overloading**](http://courses.washington.edu/css342/zander/css332/opoverload.html)

Answer (score 6):

As suggested in the comments you need to overload the `!=` operator, for example

```
class Animal{
public:
    int weight;

    bool operator!=(const Animal &other)
    {
        return weight != other.weight;
    }
};
```

An expression `x != y` is like a function call to this operator, in fact it is the same as `x.operator!=(y)`.